# Integração com API do Asaas boleto

Tags: php, json, api

Alguém por aqui já fez integração com o sistema de boleto do Asaas segue o link caso alguém queira da uma olhada ai

> https://asaasv3.docs.apiary.io

Queria tipo saber se o cliente pagou ou não pelo **id** da cobrança isso via PHP e JSON se alguém puder me ajudar ai passar um caminho eu não entendi nada a Documentação

tem também no GitHub

> https://github.com/softr/asaas-php-sdk

só que eu nunca entendo esse negocio de `composer` ai ta mais difícil ainda queria pegar os dados de forma de URL mais fácil se alguém me ajudar agradeço muito.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Recomendo fazer o curso de composer disponível no endereço https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_n57YVUVT2A&list=PLVSNL1PHDWvSrVzXyKxBc5cPM4sU7-c2T. Tem duração de 40 minutos no total e você vai sair entendendo de uma vez por todas.

Quanto a obter as informações sobre o status da cobrança, é possível através da API pela função:

```
// Retorna os dados da cobrança de acordo com o Id
$cobranca = $asaas->payment()->getById(123);
```

A documentação referente à duvida e a linha de comando acima pode ser encontrada aqui:
https://asaasv3.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/cobrancas/recuperar-uma-unica-cobranca

Answer (score 0):

Olá, amigo.

Partindo do principio que você já Inseriu o Boleto no sistema do Asaas, e em resposta pontual à sua pergunta, sobre "saber se o cliente pagou ou não pelo id da cobrança isso via PHP e JSON", faço da seguinte forma:

Basta configurar o Webhook do Asaas.
A cada iteração com o Asaas (Pagamento do Boleto, por exemplo) o sistema deles envia um post para o seu end-point informado no caminho do painel deles: Minha conta / Integração / Webhook para cobranças.

Em PHP, Eu fiz assim:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); // Recebo o Json 
$arr = json_decode($json, true); // Transformo para Array

// Nutro as variáveis com os valores de identificação
$event      = $arr[event];
$id_valor   = $arr[payment][externalReference];
$pay_asaas  = $arr[payment][id];
$dt_quita   = $arr[payment][confirmedDate];
$cobranca   = $arr[payment][billingType];
$invoicenum = $arr[payment][invoiceNumber];

// No caso de Pagamento Recebido...
if($event=="PAYMENT_RECEIVED")
{
   // Dá baixa no valor na sua Base de Dados... etc. sob sua demanda.
?>
```

[image: Essa é a tela onde se configura o seu End-point]